# After the update of eclipse plugin, cannot deploy due to application limit of 150MB, again and again

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, size, limit, quota

Its incredible that this issue keep apearing and google dont solve it.

You update the sdks (gwt/gae) and the eclipse plugin, and BANG!! You cannot deploy anymore.

```
java.io.IOException: Applications are limited to 157286400 bytes of resource files, you have 212487584.
```

But now I will help google to find a real final solution for this problem.

First of all, here is some people who had the same problem before:

I personally have this problem in 2011:

```
groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/application$20size$20limit/google-appengine/Xe2nX1MYKEE/B24as7k8ubwJ
```

And others:

```
groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nimbits/FY02Yq6lyMk/DWa5N-gzo7sJ
code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7676
comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/60935
```

The problem is not the application size. Its is some bug on eclipse plugin.
I know that cause this time I recovered the backup of my eclipse before the sdks and plugin updates. And I could deploy normally (same project with no alteration). Than I updated just the gwt sdk and yes, I could deploy. Than I updated the appengine sdk and yes, I could deploy. But if I go to eclipse plugin than I CANNOT.

Here is a possible cause of the problem. I founded the snipet of code of the eclipse plugin that produces the message on this link:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/AppVersionUpload.java?spec=svn450&r=450

```
if (resourceTotal > resourceLimits.maxTotalFileSize()) {
   throw new LocalIOException("Applications are limited to "
  + resourceLimits.maxTotalFileSize() + " bytes of resource files, "
  + "you have " + resourceTotal + ".");
}
```

On same page you can see that the variable resourceTotal is the sum of size of files in a directory represented a variable called basepath, which is initiated by this method:

```
private File getBasepath() {
    File path = app.getStagingDir();
    if (path == null) {
        path = new File(app.getPath());
    }
}
```

I think the problem is here. It uses the staging directory (that temporary directory created before the update), but if for some reason it returns null, it uses the app path that of course is much bigger and is not what is uploaded to gae. I think it should gives a error instead of this treatment that can end a limit quota.

Hope this can help someone in the future. I just lost 2 days of work cause of this bug. I have both versions of eclipse here with the problem and without it, if someone needs aditional info, and hope google correct this, cause I will need to upgrade the plugin some day.

[],
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once. And the cause was very different: I was logged in under a different Google account. Once I switched to the right account, the deployment went smoothly as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem.  For me it was something different again.

Frustratingly the cause of error bears absolutely no relation to the error message:
[image: misleading error message]

So, it is nothing to do with app size at all, but that I'd simply made a typo on my application name during the deploy:
[image: GAE deploy window]

easy to fix at least once I'd worked that out!